# Dialog JQuery doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I am new for `JQuery`, and trying to insert a dialog, but it doesn't work.

In HTML I declare a `div` and a `button`

```
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove" />
<div id="dialog" title="DIALOG">This is dialog</div>
```

In `JS` file "table.js" I wrote:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#remove", function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

I am using Bundle like this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/table").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/table.js"));
```

then import to _layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssTable")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table")
```

Did I miss any step or code? When I click `button` to remove, it doesn't work, when I did debug in browser, it also doesn't show any error.

By the way the function `click()` also doesn't work.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Add `$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});` before `$(document).on("click", "#remove", function () {})`

Comment: Thanks Arun,I try but it didnt work

Comment: Is there any console errors???

Comment: where can i see console errors?

Comment: Have you included jquery.ui.css?

Comment: I use other css file name cssTable.css Do i need import jquery.ui.css

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot call methods on dialog before initialization. It gives below error

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'open'

So you need to initialize it as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad. I add this code it work. the last question: i see some tuts they did have this, it still work: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/dialog/

Comment: if you see thoroughly they have just used as `$( "#remove" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});` and since you are using it as `$(document).on('click')` it should be done in the way I mentioned.